# Supply an anonymous function in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this dictionary

```
BRANDS = {
   "Toyota": { "shortname": lambda s: s[:2] },
   "Toyota Asia": { "shortname": lambda s: 'TyA' }
}
```

When cycling over the brands, I use the supplied lambda to get me a shortname for the brand. However, I would like to do some more complex things in that `lambda`. Is there a way in Python 3 to provide an anoymous function (like we can do in C# or Javascript)? I know I can create a named function using `def`, but I want all definition in the dictionary for administrative readons.

Whenever I search for anonymous functions online, I only get the lambda expressions.

Comment: Nope, lambdas are limited to a single expression. Anything longer needs to be regular `def` function

Comment: Within the single expression in a lambda, you do have the option of calling other functions, built-in or not.